# puppetlabs/firewall nat policy issue

Tags: iptables, puppet, nat, policy-routing

I'm using puppetlabs/firewall.

I need to create following iptable rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

My manifests is

```
firewall { '001 default redirection policy' :
  table => 'nat',
  chain => 'PREROUTING',
  proto => 'tcp',
  dport => '443',
  jump => 'REDIRECT',
  toports => '8443'
}
```

But, puppetlabs/firewall creates following iptable rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443 -m comment --comment "001 default
```

Comment: That rule looks truncated. Can you update with the full output?

Comment: iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443 -m comment --comment "001 default redirection policy" -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

Comment: So this is basically correct. Try using `toport` instead of `toports` if you take issue with the loading of the `multiport` module.